# Laravel 5.7 при обработке post запроса выдаёт ошибку 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: laravel

Простая форма

```
                <form method="POST" action="/foo" >
                 @csrf
                  <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
                  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
                </form>
```

В routes\web.php

```
Route::post('/foo', function () {
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '<pre>';
return;
```

При отправке формы  выдаёт ошибку

```
419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.
```

В версии 5.6 такой проблемы не было.

Если в app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken

прописать

```
    protected $except = [
    '/foo',
    //
];
```

не происходит проверка токина который отправляет форма и ошибка не появляется.

Маршрут отрабатывает и выдаёт

```
Array
(
    [_token] => hnaGkZ6THI0pzVVlQD23jRRYQqIrQDtXGkK4ng2Z
    [name] => Саша
)
```

Вопрос какие настройки нужно изменить чтобы посредник VerifyCsrfToken всё таки автоматически отрабатывал проверку. Получается токен который отправляет форма не получает посредник. Просто взять и отключить проверку маршрута по моему не есть хорошо.

Comment: Попробуйте в форме сделать не @csrf, a {{csrf_field()}}

Comment: Все варианты перепробовал токин в форме есть. Даже в ответе видно что токен в массив $_POST из формы попадает. Вопрос что в версии 5.7 изменили что последник этот токен не понимает, не получает.

Comment: @СашаХакеренко у меня стоит 5.7.6. Скопировал Ваш код, вставил, работает без ошибок

Comment: Может это связано с OpenServer ...

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит с токенами csrf. Они больше всего времени действуют только 1 или 2 часа. Разумеется, это зависит от времени, которое вы установили в своем конфиге. Если вы откроете `config/session.php`, вы можете найти ключ, называемый временем жизни. Это продолжительность жизни в минутах. Таким образом, токен CSRF имеет тот же диапазон времени жизни, что и этот параметр конфигурации. Поэтому, если вы отправляете сообщение на свой сервер через два часа, вы получите это исключение, потому что токен/сеанс истек.

Но также эта ошибка может быть из-за того что Вы не указали токен вовсе(я вижу что конкретно Вы указали, я для других людей). Укажите это в своем теге `form`:

```
@csrf
```

или

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

или

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/foo">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="knG4ltT7Y08UHIm6XgLSDToEzwsbLDzsIC0jnTWM">
                    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add">

                </form>Форму просмотрел с ней всё нормально

Comment: у Вас это каждый раз при отправке происходит?

Comment: С формой всё в порядке. Время сесии пробовал менять это не из-за этого. Скорее всего в версии 5.7 принципы борьбы с атаками csrf изменились и посредник по другому работет чтото нужно донастраивать.

Comment: форму я скоприровал с браузера там видно что директива @csrf работает правильно но её не достаточно как это было в Laravel 5.6.

Comment: это странно, по такой ошибке в гугле [мало результатов](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22Sorry%2C+your+session+has+expired.+Please+refresh+and+try+again%22&oq=%22Sorry%2C+your+session+has+expired.+Please+refresh+and+try+again%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.975j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: 5.7 только вышла поэтому ... я установил на прошлой неделе и сразу и на простеньком post запросе столкнулся .

Comment: Как решили данную проблему ? У меня сейчас тоже такая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется нужно еще раз вам проверить все файлы конфигураци. Что-то где-то не то прописано. Да, эта ошибка в основном связана с CSRF. Где-то у вас недопрописано в конфигурации, поэтому так мало советов. Тут все указано верно.
Но я бы советовал для тестов все-таки использовать функции вывода Ларавель.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::any('/foo', function (Request $request) {
dump($request);
});
```

У меня в проектах это появляется только если я пропускаю @scrf. 
И да! Конечно проверить на стороне броузера что данный ИНПУТ с Токеном раскрылся. Может просто Кэш View сбросить.

еще для проверки сделайте в форме метод не post а get и посмотрите в ответе на форму в массиве dump($request) есть ли Токен (_token) в группе request.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.7 Админка Voyager. На Frontend - React 16 После исправлений в файлах перестало заходить в админку. При вводе логина и пароля выдавало ошибку 419. В моем случае в файле routes/api.php перед открывающим тегом был добавлен пробел. Это и было ошибкой. После удаления все нормализовалось.

Просто все говорят про CSRF, а проблема может оказаться в более примитивных вещах. О которых говорят гораздо реже.

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема с редиректом на страницу с ошибкой 419, проблема возникала при авторизации или регистрации пользователя. Форма была создана стандартными средствами Laravel, а именно командой `php artisan make:auth`, И стабильно работала пару недель, потом появился редирект. Попробовал удалить и переустановить vendor и обновить laravel, как это описано тут => [laravel-update](http://cccp-blog.com/laravel/laravel-update) (Может кому пригодится) - Мне это не помогло.

Решение проблемы:

В файле `auth/login.blade.php` я заменил вызов `CSRF` с `@csrf` на `{{csrf_field()}}`, сбросил кэш `php artisan cofig:cache` и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describes in detail. http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/csrf 
Or as mentioned above, add a token. 
Or, add the route to the exception in the application/nttr/intermediate/VerifyCsrfToken file.in PHP in an array of protected 
$except = [
        '/test_page'
];

Comment: Почему вы решили написать по английски? Русский не ваш родной язык и вам трудно писать по-русски?